# My React Application is not working correctly on my PC

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem and I do not really think is about my code but my computer perhaps?
I'm working with a team on a react application. We are all learning in this.

Our Front End needs to request some information from the Back End and then show it on our site. This code works perfectly with all the team members... but for some reason, the same code (even when I clone the project from my team members) the backend in my terminal never shows anything to the Front End even if the terminal says is loaded.

There are no errors given.... is just simply not working on my computer and nothing changes in my react application.

I tried checking the code, but the code is totally fine, as I mentioned before... my team members don't have any problem is just me.

Is there any feature from Windows 10 PC that I should check that is doing conflict with my react without telling me?

Note: Is my first time posting something here, please advise me if there is something extra that I need to provide. :'-(

### Info from my terminal:

```
[0] 
[0] > knowrona@1.0.0 server C:\Users\jalej\OneDrive\Desktop\Programacion\knowrona
[0] > nodemon server.js
[0]
[1]
[1] > knowrona@1.0.0 client C:\Users\jalej\OneDrive\Desktop\Programacion\knowrona
[1] > npm start --prefix client
[1]
[0] [nodemon] 2.0.4
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[0] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[1] 
[1] > client@0.1.0 start C:\Users\jalej\OneDrive\Desktop\Programacion\knowrona\client
[1] > react-scripts start
[1]
[0] Server running on port 5000
[1] i ｢wds｣: Project is running at _____________ :-)
[1] i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
[1] i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\jalej\OneDrive\Desktop\Programacion\knowrona\client\public
[1] i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
[1] Starting the development server...
[1]
[1] Compiled with warnings.
[1]
[1] ./src/components/ProfileIcon/ProfileIcon.js
[1]   Line 10:22:  Unexpected empty object pattern
                                  no-empty-pattern
[1]   Line 13:7:   Redundant alt attribute. Screen-readers already announce `img` tags as an image. You don’t need to use the words `image`, `photo,` or `picture` (or any specified custom words) in the alt prop  jsx-a11y/img-redundant-alt
[1]
[1] ./src/QuizSession/Question/Question.js
[1]   Line 37:39:   Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return
[1]   Line 116:24:  Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='           eqeqeq
[1]
[1] ./src/Home/Home.js
[1]   Line 39:5:  Expected a default case  default-case
[1]   Line 56:9:  Unreachable code         no-unreachable
[1]   Line 67:9:  Unreachable code         no-unreachable
[1]   Line 72:9:  Unreachable code         no-unreachable
[1]
[1] Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
[1] To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
[1]
[0] loaded
[0] loaded
[0] loaded
[0] loaded
[0] loaded
[0] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
[0] loaded
[0] loaded
[0] loaded
[0] loaded
```

Comment: Is your backend working as expected? Did you test it Postman? What debugging techniques did you try in the react side?

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017` - so something is expecting that something else runs on your computer, which it doesn't.

Comment: 27017 is the default port of MongoDB, and looks like the application is trying to access that. You could figure out/check with your team members if you need to have a mongodb instance running on your system or do you need to point to one that is owned by your team.

Comment: you need to start the MongoDB instance.

Comment: Thx Guys!  I was missing MongoDB!   Now everything is going well!! Thank you!!!  <3

Answer (score 0):

"*27017 is the default port of MongoDB, and looks like the application is trying to access that. You could figure out/check with your team members if you need to have a mongodb instance running on your system or do you need to point to one that is owned by your team*"

So what I did was to Install MongoDB which was missing and then I install the extension in VS Code.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/mongodb